# MySQL select from multiple tables using pivot

Tags: mysql, inner-join, pivot-table

I have a many-to-many relationship between two tables, and I am using a pivot table to manage it.
The structure is as follows:

- **Table 1**: cars (car_id, ...)
- **Table 2**: brands (brand_id, ...)
- **Pivot table**: cars_brands (car_id, brand_id, units, discount)

Using only one query, I am trying to select every field of the cars of a certain brand PLUS the number of units and discount (both fields of the pivot table...)

My try:

```
SELECT c.*, cb.units, cb.discount 
FROM (cars c, cars_brands cb) 
INNER JOIN cb ON c.car_id = cb.car_id 
WHERE cb.brand_id = 1 
ORDER BY c.car_id asc
```

I am getting a

> `#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'cb'`

MySQL error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to join with the `brands` table somewhere. Is `Audi` really a `brand_id`, not `brands.name`?

Comment: I guess your query is not complete inner join misses the table name also if you are using same table twice then you need give them unique aliases like `cars_brands cb`  and `cars_brands cb1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
SELECT c.*, cb.units. cb.discount
FROM cars AS c
JOIN car_brands as cb ON cb.car_id = c.car_id
JOIN brands AS b ON b.brand_id = cb.brand_id
WHERE b.brand_name = 'Audi'
ORDER BY c.car_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also:-

select c.*,cb.units,cb.discount from  car c,brands b,cars_brands cb where c.car_id=cb.car_id and b.brand_id=cb.brand_id and cb.brand_id=8888 order by cb.car_id asc;